# Ruby array processing add an unexpected nil to the new array?

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby (coming from Python) and try to experiment this exercise:
(mixed the array items by taking first, last in rotating fashion)
Expected Output to be - [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]. But I did not expect 'nil' at the end... The orig. array can contain even or odd size of numbers.

Can someone shed the light of this unexpected?  Thanks in advance.
[Updates - re-write the example from Ruby Cookbook p.162  *Array* ]

```
nums = (1..7).to_a   # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 

mixed = []
#middle = nums.length / 2

#index = 0

until nums.empty?
  mixed << nums.shift().  #get 1st element out
  mixed << nums.pop()     #get last element out
  #index += 1
  
end

print mixed    # Got [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, nil]
```

Comment: Because after you `shift` the last value off you then `pop`, perhaps forgetting to see if there is any data left. Put left finger at the start of the array, right at the end. When you say `shift` move your left finger to the right; when you say `pop` move your right finger to the left. See?

Comment: Hey, @DaveNewton - can you elaborate a little more, or share the pointers? Thanks.

Comment: There is literally nothing to elaborate on. Your code currently assumes an even number of array elements.

Comment: Irb output

`[].pop # => nil`
`[].shift #=> nil
`
So last step in your example will produce `nil` since you have 2 operations in one iteration

Comment: Thanks, @andriy-baran - got it.  To be more precise, I did not expect the orig. array contains even numbers. [updates]

Comment: Also note that this could be tested in `irb`. Just don't use the loop; create your array, and unroll the loop "by hand".

Comment: In python this would've crashed with a "IndexError: pop from empty list". Not sure if I'd prefer if ruby did that instead of returning nil

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that the total num of elements in the array is odd so the last value is put into mixed on 'shift' and then there is no element left in the array. This will solve your issue:

```
nums = (1..7).to_a   # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 

mixed = []
#middle = nums.length / 2

#index = 0

until nums.empty?
  mixed << nums.shift()
  mixed << nums.pop() unless nums.empty?
  #index += 1
  
end

print mixed    # Got [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
```

Another way is: If the num of elements is odd then run the loop till n-1 and then get the last element out using shift/pop (doesn't matter if you use shift or pop at the end, you will get the same element.)

Comment: Another way to avoid the boundary condition is to perform only one operation within the loop, i.e. cycling between `shift` and `pop` instead of attempting both.

Answer (score 1):

The Cookbook method can be made non-destructive (avoid modifying `nums`) as follows.

```
def doit(nums)
  nums.size.times.map { |i| i.even? ? nums[i/2] : nums[-i/2] }
end
```

```
doit [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  #=> [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
doit [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
  #=> [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5]
```

Here is another (non-destructive) way to do that.

```
def doit(nums)
  n = nums.size/2
  nums.first(n).zip(nums.last(n).reverse).flatten.tap do |a|
    a << nums[n] if nums.size.odd?
  end
end
```

```
doit [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  #=> [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
doit [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
  #=> [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Like these very much. Is this more idiomatic way?

Comment: I would say "no"; just different